# Last 'OR' statement Ignored in OLEDB command

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbcommand

I'm trying to filter a OLEDB command by having multiple 'OR' statements work on a single database field but the last in the chain gets ignored and doesn't return anything.

I have a work around for now with a @null request that returns "DBNull.value" but if I remove "[doctype] = @null" from below it ignores "[doctype] = doctype3"

```
& "WHERE [doctype] = @doctype OR [doctype] = @doctype2 OR [doctype] = @doctype3 OR [doctype] = @null " _
```

I can increase or decrease the 'OR Statements' as I like but it is always the last 'OR Statement' that is ignored.

I've tried putting the 'OR statements' in brackets but then it returns nothing, or I'm doing it wrong.

I'm looking for simply why the last 'or statement' is ignored in the oledbcommand string but if you can improve any code I've wrote please do, but explain to me why/how.

Where they are used (Every other value has DBNull.value for testing purposes)

```
            f_doctype = "MS"
            f_doctype2 = "TMS"
            f_doctype3 = "CS"

            With cmdaRefresh.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("doctype", CType(f_doctype, String))
            .AddWithValue("doctype2", CType(f_doctype2, String))
            .AddWithValue("doctype3", CType(f_doctype3, String))
            .AddWithValue("null", DBNull.Value)
            .AddWithValue("docnum", DBNull.Value)
            .AddWithValue("docrev", DBNull.Value)
            .AddWithValue("matname", DBNull.Value)
            .AddWithValue("status", DBNull.Value)
            .AddWithValue("actionreq", DBNull.Value)
            .AddWithValue("createdby", DBNull.Value)
            .AddWithValue("createddate", DBNull.Value)
            .AddWithValue("finalby", DBNull.Value)
            .AddWithValue("finaldate", DBNull.Value)
            End With

        Dim cmdRefresh As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdaRefresh)

        'open connection
        myconnection.Open()

        'read and fill dataset for gridview
        cmdRefresh.Fill(dsRefresh, tbl_string.tablename)

        'close connection
        myconnection.Close()

'fill datagrid with values from database and alter column headers to match criteria
        With dg_speclog
            .DataSource = dsRefresh.Tables(0)
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Category"
            ...
        End With
```

Full 'oledbcommand' creation

```
Dim cmdaRefresh As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(" SELECT [doctype], [docnum], [docrev], [matname], [status], [actionreq], [createdby], [createddate], [finalby], [finaldate] " _
                                                              & "FROM " & tbl_string.tablename & " " _
                                                              & "WHERE [doctype] = @doctype OR [doctype] = @doctype2 OR [doctype] = @doctype3 OR [doctype] = @null " _
                                                              & "AND [docnum] = @docnum " _
                                                              & "AND [docrev] = @docrev " _
                                                              & "AND [matname] = @matname " _
                                                              & "AND [status] = @status " _
                                                              & "AND [actionreq] = @actionreq " _
                                                              & "AND [createdby] = @createdby " _
                                                              & "AND [createddate] = @createddate " _
                                                              & "AND [finalby] = @finalby " _
                                                              & "AND [finaldate] = @finaldate " _
                                                              & "ORDER BY [docnum] ASC, [docrev] ASC " _
                                                              , myconnection)
```

Comment: Sounds like all those `AND` conditions are never all true, and due to operator precedence they are being combined with the final `OR`ed condition.  Start by adding parens around the `OR`ed conditions.  You also need to use `IS NULL` for null checks, not `=`.  e.g. `WHERE ([doctype] = @doctype OR [doctype] = @doctype2 OR [doctype] = @doctype3 OR [doctype] IS NULL) AND [docnum] = @docnum AND ...`.  You'll need to work out why the `AND`s aren't true - could be that a parameter isn't being set correctly, but they weren't included in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that, I'm going to take out all the extra parameters now just to check if it is the `AND`s breaking the `OR`s. Could you comment on how you would do the parens around the `OR`s, I've tried but it ends up returning nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason why it wasn't working. Somewhere during my search I read that `DBNull.value` would return anything from the database when used with a `.addwithvalue` statement (which might of confused the whole thing). Which is not correct, it returns anything that has a value of `nothing` as in `no white space or value`. Which is why `[doctype] IS NULL` gave the same issue as above, it does the same thing, I think.

What I was looking for was a way to search through my `[doctype]`'s and return any value from the other database fields without having to specify anything 'for testing'

The statement I was looking for was `[docnum] LIKE '%'` this is called a Wildcard. A wildcard character can be used to substitute for any other character(s) in a string, so that mean anything is returned. However if the database field is of value `Null` then a `IS NULL` statement is still require, hence my `[finalyby] & [finaldate]` alterations below.

What I've came up with now is:

```
'CHANGED (dataadapter > command)
    Dim cmdaRefresh As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(" SELECT [doctype], [docnum], [docrev], [matname], [status], [actionreq], [createdby], [createddate], [finalby], [finaldate] " _
                                                              & "FROM " & tbl_string.tablename & " " _
                                                              & "WHERE [doctype] IN (@doctype, @doctype2 ,@doctype3) " _
                                                              & "AND [docnum] LIKE '%' " _
                                                              & "AND [docrev] LIKE '%' " _
                                                              & "AND [matname] LIKE '%' " _
                                                              & "AND [status] LIKE '%' " _
                                                              & "AND [actionreq] LIKE '%' " _
                                                              & "AND [createdby] LIKE '%' " _
                                                              & "AND [createddate] LIKE '%' " _
                                                              & "AND ([finalby] LIKE '%' OR [finalby] IS NULL) " _
                                                              & "AND ([finaldate] LIKE '%' OR [finaldate] IS NULL) " _
                                                              & "ORDER BY [docnum] ASC, [docrev] ASC " _
                                                              , myconnection)
```

Thank you to who helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IS NULL` to check for null values (in most, perhaps all, databases, null does not equal null, so you need to use the `IS` operator instead).  This also means you don't need all those parameters.

Depending on how you intend to combine the `[doctype] IS NULL` check with the other null checks, you *may* also need to wrap the `OR`s in parentheses, since `AND` may have higher precedence than `OR`.

```
Dim cmdaRefresh As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(
    " SELECT [doctype], [docnum], [docrev], [matname], [status], [actionreq], [createdby], [createddate], [finalby], [finaldate] " _
    & "FROM " & tbl_string.tablename & " " _
    & "WHERE ([doctype] = @doctype OR [doctype] = @doctype2 OR [doctype] = @doctype3 OR [doctype] IS NULL) " _
    & "AND [docnum] IS NULL " _
    & "AND [docrev] IS NULL " _
    & "AND [matname] IS NULL " _
    & "AND [status] IS NULL " _
    & "AND [actionreq] IS NULL " _
    & "AND [createdby] IS NULL " _
    & "AND [createddate] IS NULL " _
    & "AND [finalby] IS NULL " _
    & "AND [finaldate] IS NULL " _
    & "ORDER BY [docnum] ASC, [docrev] ASC " _
    , myconnection)
```

If the`[doctype] IS NULL` check belongs with the other `NULL` checks then you don't need the parens.

Comment: I have played around with your suggestion and putting parens around the `OR` statements makes it return nothing, without them and only the `IS NULL` parts it works.... But my problem is still that I have the pointless `[doctype] IS NULL` in the `Where` statement.. If I remove it the return ignores `[doctype] = @doctype3` and only give values for `@doctype and @doctype2`.. Likewise if I add in a forth return `[doctype] = @doctype4` it will give me values for `@doctype, @doctype2, @doctype3` but ignore `@doctype4`.. only when I have a sacrificial `[doctype] IS NULL` in the `OR` chain it works...